# What is the proper way to keep one-off data?

Tags: python, django

I've got online shop on Django, where I want to keep some information like address or mobile phone of manager, but this information should be simply-edited by admin of the site. So, I couldn't leave it just as text in template or variable in code, because now I need to create some forms for editing this information.
I don't sure what to do: create model Info in my database with all fields which I want to keep or create couple of models for each. Or maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with having a table in your database that only has one row.  In designing systems, it is common to have pieces of data that do not change often, but can change.  In systems that will be installed at multiple sites, this might be configuration settings like enable/disable feature A, or feature B, or which of three different methods to use for a certain calculation.  In systems that will only have one installation, it might be the local sales tax rate, or who to contact, if needed, and how.  Rather than hard-coding this information so that only a programmer can change it, this should be placed in a data store where it can be edited and updated by a user/power user/administrator.  This can be in the main data store for the system, in a text configuration file, or in the windows registry.

The windows registry would not be very appropriate for a server based python/django application.  Python has a built-in `configparser` module which does a good job of keeping this type of information in a text file alongside the program(s).  Other languages, I am sure, have similar functionality available.   Django has an ORM to a relational database built in.  Most (all?) django applications will be using the ORM/RDBMS functionality.  I cannot see a reason to add another module (`configparser`) to an application that already has the ability to store/retrieve this information conveniently and reliably.  That is just adding complexity to the system.

That leaves storing in the main datastore/RDBMS.  This is very convenient in Django because of the availability of the admin interface to allow editing.  There are two main approaches to storing these pieces of data in a database.  I will call these wide, and long.  Wide configuration storage consists of a single row of data with a specified column for each piece of data required.

> ```
>  Name     |    Phone    | tax rate |  ftr A | ftr B | …     
> Joe Smith | 1234567890  |7.6       | Y      | N     | …
> ```

Long configuration stores key value pairs – similar to a python `dict`:

> ```
>  Key                  |    value     
>  Name                 | Joe Smith   
>  Phone                | 1234567890   
>  Feature A            | Y    
>  …                    | …
> ```

Wide configuration has a drawback in that adding another piece of information requires modifying the data storage model (data dictionary, file layout, …).  Wide configuration retrieves all the data in just one read.  Which can mean retrieving unneeded data.

Long configuration allows adding another piece of information simply by adding another row to the table.  But, requires different tables for different types of data (string, int, float).  Long configuration also requires multiple reads to get multiple pieces of data that may be related.

The most appropriate approach for a given project depends on factors like how much data, what type of data, and what is done with the data.  It is commonly a combination of approaches.